# Send mail when ever case is created with attachment

Tags: visualforce

When ever i am creating a case with attachment, After creation of case with attachment i want to send a mail,Here Case is creating with attachment but mail not sent .........Can any one help me on this below is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="case" extensions="caseattachment">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Case Edit" id="pb">
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Information" collapsible="false">
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Case Owner"/>
                  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}"/>    
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!objcase.status}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!objcase.origin}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!objcase.Type}"/>  
                  <apex:inputField value="{!objcase.AccountId}"/>              
                  <apex:inputField value="{!objcase.contactId}"/>              
           </apex:pageBlockSection>
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
               <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="Uploading the attachments" collapsible="false">
               <div id="upload" class="upload">
               <apex:inputFile value="{!filebody}" fileName="{!fileName}" id="fileToUpload"/>
               </div>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

```
public class caseattachment {

 public case objcase{get;set;}
 public string fileName{get;set;} 
 public Blob fileBody{get;set;}
 public Attachment myAttachment{get;set;}

    public caseattachment(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
    objcase = new case();
    myAttachment = new Attachment();
    sendmail();
    }
  public pagereference save()
  {
   insert objcase;
  myAttachment = new Attachment();
  integer i = 0;
  myAttachment.clear();
  myAttachment.Body=fileBody;
  myAttachment.Name = 'Logo_'+objcase.id+'.jpeg' ; 
  myAttachment.ParentId = objcase.id;             

  insert myAttachment;                 
  pagereference pr = new pagereference('/apex/addingattachmentoncaseobject');                           
  return pr;
  }
   public void sendmail(){
     if(objcase!=null && myAttachment!=null){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'abcd@gmail.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Case creation');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Case creation');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
   }
 }
```

Comment: In the save method after the insert of attachment  your should call 'sendmail' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `sendmail()` from the Save method and not from the controller. Your method not actually get called once you save the record thats why you didn't get the email.

```
//some code
insert myAttachment;    
sendmail();
// code continue
```

Comment: @Mahendra then you can accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: I am new here,can you please help me how to close the question.

Comment: @Mahendra JFI when any answer solve your problem and you accept that. It is mark as closed